# Ember Data attributes not being camelized

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Here's a sample of the JSON

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "10",
            "email": "test8@test.org",
            "activated": true,
            "created_at": "2013-08-25 19:30:16",
            "username": "Roober"
        }
    ]
}
```

This works:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr(),
    email: DS.attr(),
    activated: DS.attr(),
    created_at: DS.attr()
});
```

This does not:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr(),
    email: DS.attr(),
    activated: DS.attr(),
    createdAt: DS.attr()
});
```

createdAt returns undefined.

Ember is v1.0.0 and Ember Data is v1.0.0-beta.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember data beta 1 expect a CamelCase response from your server by default
but you can implement the normalize method to change that :

```
normalize: function(type, hash, property) {
    var json = { id: hash.id };

    for (var prop in hash) {
      json[prop.camelize()] = hash[prop]; 
    }

    return this._super(type, json, property);
}
```

You can look at this document for more information https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md.

Comment: Thanks. That means the docs are wrong http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_underscored-attribute-names

Comment: In the latest builds `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` and `DS.ActiveModelSerializer` have also been working for me

Comment: I think that they must be trying to phase out that particular document.  It's not linked in any of the menus, and I've submitted a couple of pull requests to correct that page and they have not been accepted for weeks even though they update the page to accurately reflect the current functionality.